# apply increase over non-existent values replacing them with zero

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have an unscheduled batch job that may or may not be triggered multiple times a day. For every invocation, I'm generating a count metric incremented by 1.

I expected to apply `increase()` function over 1 day for the metric and see a spike for every invocation of that day.

However, I noticed increase function doesn't show or extrapolate data for extended missing period (like the period before adding these metrics) and hence the first invocation always makes zero increments.

I'm trying something like `increase(job_invocation_total[1d])`.

I also tried to set the non-existent values as zero with `OR on() vector(0)` but `increase()` function didn't allow it.

Similarly for `clamp_min()`

I'm pretty sure there must be a standard way of achieving it but unfortunately, I can't think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the code where the metric `job_invocation_total` is created **and** the cardinality of the metric labels is bound, you can initialize the counter with the value 0.

If this is not the case, you can create a recording rule that is either 0 or equal to the metric `job_invocation_total`.

Comment: Yes, I did initialize it with zero on application restart and that had indeed fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The way I sorted this problem was doing the following prometheus query for Grafana. This query allows me to identify the `total_processing_time` consumed by an individual customer across all PODs in a K8s cluster within a given time range. The catch is that this query handles the following corner cases:

- If the querying time_range encompasses only the last 1h but there are older timeseries that were started before that, the query below "offsets to zero" these timeseries by removing the value of the first measurement point within the time_range. This way these series are considered as if they have started within the time range.
- If a new timeseries (due to a new POD) show up within the querying time_range, and the first measurement value is greater than 0, then the first measurement value of the new timeseries is added to the calculation to fulfill the gap from the `increment` function.

```yaml
sum(
    # Calculates the difference between the last measurement 
    # and the first measurement in the given time_range for each 
    # timeseries, this helps identify how much additional resources
    # were consumed in the given time_range
    increase(
        total_processing_time{customer_id="$customer_id"}[$__range]
    )
    # Adds to the difference the minimum value of each timeseries, 
    # this helps to account for the timeseries that started within 
    # the given time_range with the first measurement greater than 0
    # (not considered by the previous increase function)
    + min_over_time(
        total_processing_time{customer_id="$customer_id"}[$__range]
    )
)
# Removes the timeseries measurements being carried over from before 
# the start of the time_range, this offsets the running timeseries
# as if they had started from zero within the time_range
- sum(
    total_processing_time{customer_id="$customer_id"} @ start() or vector(0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what number you're asking for, but `changes(push_time_seconds[1d])` would give you the number of times it pushed to the pushgateway in the past day.

Comment: This may be similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63891162/how-to-detect-a-new-metrics-with-prometheus-alerting-rule/63935356#63935356. You may want to comment on my answer since I made an assumption about increase().